# Interpret URL correctly which port is the webserver listening to?

Tags: ssl, web-server, port, url, port-443

I have a webserver running which i didnt install. The URL to reach the webserver is https://adomain.de:7535

I took a look at the respective service unit and noticed its listening on port 7535 (--port=7535).
So i am wondering how that works and how i should interpret the URL, because i have a valid SSL certificate, so i always thought the webserver is listening on 443 and not 7535.
This is confusing me. Can someone clarify my misunderstanding?

Comment: needs more details, however it sounds like an offtopic question without any further information but i think its going to be a private question instead of a business related issue

Comment: could be an offtopic question, but my qestion was answered.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is quite simple.

The ports you assume (443 SSL) are DEFAULT. The URL overrides it. Done.

It goes with https to port 7535 and the server listens to that port with the ssl certificate. The SSL certificate HAS NO PORT NUMBER IN IT.

> so i always thought the webserver is listening on 443

That is the default. Clearly the default is changed in the server configuration, though the server may ALSO listen on port 443 - you could test that.